# WPF Binding Source

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have searched over a week to find an answer but I couldn't.

because of some reasone i have to implement `Windows.Data.Binding` my self. so I created a Class and put a private `Binding` object in that like this:

```
Public Class Binding
Inherits MarkupExtension
Private _Binding As New Windows.Data.Binding

#Region "Properties"

Public Property ElementName() As String
    Get
        Return _Binding.ElementName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Binding.ElementName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Mode() As BindingMode
    Get
        Return _Binding.Mode
    End Get
    Set(value As BindingMode)
        _Binding.Mode = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Source() As Object
    Get
        Return _Binding.Source
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        _Binding.Source = value
    End Set
End Property
#End Region
'*Other Properties of Windows.Data.Binding go inside region*

Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As IServiceProvider) As Object
    If serviceProvider Is Nothing Then
        Return "Design Time"
    Else
        Dim k = _Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider)
        Return k
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

It worked.
I need to change some implementations in `ProvideValue` and for doing that, I Need to find the source of binding. for example I have an object in XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={local:Binding Path=UserID} />
```

ok, my `TextBlock` is bound to `UserID` of **What...**??

the question is **What's the source of binding?** and **how can i access that in `ProvideValue` Method?**

Thanks to all

Comment: I am wondering why would you need to implement your own binding, you can make use of converters, format string etc.

Comment: It's an idea.
I'm Writing a public DLL which will be shared on all projects of this company, suppose that there are several projects and several users which `UserAccess` matters in each project.
I want to limit access of user to the specific columns of tables, thus, i don't want to other developers get rush in that strategy, they just bind to proper tables and proper columns, but **Myy**`Binding` decide that if this user can read those values or not!
I don't know if I could say clear or not :/

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample for how to use service provider to get the targets & source of binding

```
Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As IServiceProvider) As Object
    Dim service As IProvideValueTarget = DirectCast(serviceProvider.GetService(GetType(IProvideValueTarget)), IProvideValueTarget)
    Dim targetObject As DependencyObject = TryCast(service.TargetObject, DependencyObject)
    Dim targetProperty As DependencyProperty = TryCast(service.TargetProperty, DependencyProperty)

    'find source of the binding'
    Dim targetElement As FrameworkElement = TryCast(targetObject, FrameworkElement)
    If targetElement IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim sourceObject As Object = targetElement.DataContext

        'your logic here'
    End If
End Function
```

I would suggest to create your own binding extension only if you are not able to achieve the same using converters and formats and also if there is a specific need to do that.

read here for more info on IServiceProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621338.aspx

Comment: thank you for taking time
Maybe I couldn't describe better.
but `targetProperty` Refers to the `Text` property of `TextBlock` where the `targetObject` is the same `<TextBlock .../>`.
I want to reach to **Source**, not the **Target**.

Comment: thank you again,
I've tried this before, but the problem is:

As you know `ProvideValue` function is called just once, thus, if we pass DataContext in Run-time, it's impossible to detect `DataContext` type in `ProvideValue`!

thank you again because of time, and precision.

Comment: That is a complex handling via notification change etc. For this I would suggest you to derive your class from BindingBase class instead of MarkupExtension as most of the handling is done there.